# Primary Key not incrementing in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Okay so this is happening throughout my application, it will only allow me to have 1 entry in my Database before throwing this error:

`Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__UserSess__23DB122B80549C92'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserSessions'. The duplicate key value is (0).
The statement has been terminated.`

The primary key is not auto-incrementing as I've experienced before.

I've tried changing the property "StoreGeneratedPattern" to Identity and all I just get an error saying the primary key entry can't be null.

The primary key is named "sessionId". This happens with every table, the primary keys do not self increment whenever I attempt to add new data to the database, do I have to manually increment it? I don't think I've EVER had to do that with Entity Framework.

```
            UserSession sess = db.UserSessions.Add(new UserSession
            {
                timeCreated = DateTime.Now,
                expirationTime = timeToExpire,
                userId = uc.userId,
                sessionHash = Security.generateSessionId(),
            });

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

User Sessions design:

[image: UserSessions Design]

Please someone relieve my anger, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this issue pretty quickly but I've never had to do this with Entity Framework before.

In the database design I had to change:

`[sessionId] INT NOT NULL`

to the following:

`[sessionId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1)`

Comment: FYI - this isn't Entity Frameworks issue here.  If you do not tell MSSQL that this is an `IDENTITY` column, how could it distinguish between this and any other `INT` column.  Just setting a primary key does not make a column *auto increment*.  An example would be a table of people using their SSN as a primary key.  Sure, horrible design from a security perspective, but it is an example of a non-auto incrementing primary key.  That is why you have to set the column as an `IDENTITY`

Comment: Yeah but previously it sorted this automatically for me, not sure why it didn't this time. I know it's not an issue with Entity Framework but I've never had to manually.